# Reordenamento de células no Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

No momento tenho um layout que é assim, usando o Bootstrap:

```
[-nav/header]
[-1-][-2][-4]
[---3---][-4]
[---3---][-4]
[---footer--]
```

E eu gostaria de exibí-lo assim na navegação móvel:

```
[-nav/header]
[-----1-----]
[-----3-----]
[-----2-----]
[-----4-----]
[---footer--]
```

Mas somente consigo assim:

```
[-nav/header]
[-----1-----]
[-----2-----]
[-----3-----]
[-----4-----]
[---footer--]
```

Meu código é algo parecido com:

```css
.red {
background-color: red; 
}
.yellow {
background-color: yellow; 
}
.green {
background-color: green; 
}
.blue {
background-color: blue; 
}

.red, .yellow, .green, .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
 }
* {
  padding: 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col xs-12">
 <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col xs-12">
  <div class="red">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col xs-12">
  <div class="yellow">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col xs-12">
  <div class="green">3</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="blue">4 - Sem nenhum problema</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @re22 Gostaria que o 3 e 2 ficassem invertidos, porém a configuração deles no desktops se mantivesse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra você conseguir reordenar conforme a resolução, teria que mudar suas divs para flex, assim você consegue usar o "order". Eu fiz um exemplo pra você que a quando a resolução for menor que 767px, ele faz o que você deseja.

http://jsfiddle.net/vwxvw9xr/

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Perfeito! Tinha usado 'position: absolute' mas sabia que tinha ficado ruim, ótima solução!